# jasmin-jquery: Testing the first element in the body - strange error

Tags: jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am trying to test the position (not CSS position, but order of elements) of a `div` element using jasmine-jquery.

The fixture looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Homepage</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="my-element"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the corresponding test:

```
describe('My HTML', function() {
    loadFixtures('test.html');

    it('have a first child with class my-element', function() {
        expect($('body').children().first()).toHaveClass('my-element');
    });
});
```

Unfortunately this test fails with a pretty cryptic message:

```
Expected ({ 0: HTMLNode, length: 1, prevObject: ({ 0: HTMLNode, 1: HTMLNode, 2: HTMLNode, 3: HTMLNode, 4: HTMLNode, 5: HTMLNode, 6: HTMLNode, 7: HTMLNode, 8: HTMLNode, 9: HTMLNode, 10: HTMLNode, 11: HTMLNode, 12: HTMLNode, length: 13, prevObject: ({ 0: HTMLNode, length: 1, prevObject: ({ 0: HTMLNode, context: HTMLNode, length: 1 }), context: HTMLNode, selector: 'body' }), context: HTMLNode }), context: HTMLNode }) to have class 'my-element'.
```

Could anybody help me please, what is going on there? Why does the test fail?

Comment: I think the issue is that your fixture is getting injected into the page with Jasmine which means the `body` tag that you think your are getting is not the `body` in the fixture but the `body` of the page that is hosting Jasmine and your specs.  Is there another way to write that test?  Do you have to verify that your element is the first child after the body?  Also, you might try taking all the head/body stuff out of your fixture and simply do `<div class=myelement></div>` as the full fixture.

Comment: @mrrogers Wow, never thought of that! But you are probably right since logging `$('body').children().first()` returns a script element. Still it looks like when I add a second `it`, that second call always fails. Any idea why?

Comment: Adding more `it` blocks will not change the structure.  The test harness will simply run your specs against the DOM which now contains your fixture.   You probably need to make you're test query smarter (or maybe stupider).  Is it enough to do `expect($('.my-element')).toBeInDOM()`?  If you are looking for a specific order of elements, you may need to either write your own custom matchers or simply do the custom element lookup in the spec.  Side note - you should probably wrap your `loadFixtures` call in a `beforeEach()`.